# git ssh config file error

Tags: git, ssh

I'm trying to add multi ssh file in my Mac, I save my ssh config file as:

```
Host github
    HostName github.com
    User fizix100
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
```

but it didn't work, and show me an error when I'm trying to pull remote files:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree fetch origin 
/Users/fengzhenxing/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: user:fizix100
/Users/fengzhenxing/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Completed with errors, see above
```

Comment: Try using new configuration file, as error message is still old - `/Users/fengzhenxing/.ssh/config: line 3: Bad configuration option: user:fizix100`

Comment: What error message do you have now that you have edited your ssh config file?

Comment: @fizix100 Accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove colon from `User` directive of your ssh config

```
Host github
    HostName github.com
    User fizix100
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
```